# How do you create a simple Objective-C command line project in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

I'm moving from a C# VS2008 world into the Mac world and I just wanted to know how I can create a quick little command line based application so that I can write many little Objective-C apps without worrying about creating an iPhone app or whatever.

Which projects do I create in Xcode? I can see the Command Line Tool under "Mac OS X" but the only options for the type is "C", "C++", "Core Data", "Core Foundation", "Core Services" and "Foundation" but no simple Objective-C project ?

Thanks

Answer (score 62, accepted):

"Foundation" is the one you want. The Foundation framework is Apple's "standard library" for Objective-C that provides all the basic classes like NSArray, NSString, NSNumber, and much more. Since "plain" Objective-C without Foundation is not very useful for most applications, Apple probably chose to name its project template after the Foundation library.

Comment: @Warren P: that's not true. As of Xcode 4.5.2, the Type selection for a Command Line Tool app is still there.

Comment: Did I miss it? i saw no such selection as "Foundation Tool", only, as you say, a general command line tool, which does not include the foundation framework import or includes.  My original comment was incorrect or confusing. Is this a clearer statement?

Comment: In Xcode 4.5: click File > New > Project > OS X > Application > Command Line Tool > Next. Then choose the type of your command line tool ("Foundation", among others) with the Type popup.