# Can I run Objective-C programs (not iPhone/Mac projects) in Xcode like executing C programs?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, macos

I am working in Mac system. Is it possible to run Objective-C programs in Xcode? I am not talking about running iPhone/Mac projects. I am talking about simple Objective-C programs, like we run C programs in C editors. Does Xcode has the provision for this? Or, I have to use some other editors? Which editors I can use?

Please suggest me.. Thanks everyone..

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2697883/how-do-you-create-a-simple-objective-c-command-line-project-in-xcode

Comment: @David Gelhar: Exactly what I want.. Thank you so much..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2697883/how-do-you-create-a-simple-objective-c-command-line-project-in-xcode) from David Gelhar's comment on my question has the answer for this question.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need Xcode to run a program. You can just execute a program from the command line or by double-clicking. (You also do not need an editor to run a C program.)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.. SO link in @David Gelhar's comment above, has the answer for me..

Answer (score 2):

Foundation is the one that you want

On xcode 4.4 its under OSX -> Application -> Command Line Tool

And change the option to Foundation